# Rosalind resolution noob

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics, rosalind

This is my solution to the problem presented here: http://rosalind.info/problems/subs/.

```
def subs(string,subString):
    lista=[]
    i=0
    while i < (len(string)-len(subString)):
        if string[i:(i+len(subString)-1)]==subString:
           lista.append(i)
        i+=1
    return lista
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Indentation is wrong.

Comment: Can you tell me where, please?

Comment: Everywhere, but I think that it's only a result of bad copy/paste and the indentation is fine on your side inside your text editor.

Comment: You are right. My fault. Thank you @NorthCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that's wrong with it is that you can't add an integer to a list, you need to append it:

```
lista.append(i)
```

Then the slice is too short: in Python, `a[i:j]` gives you all characters from position `i` up to *but not including* position `j`. Because you subtract 1 from the length, it will compare one character too few every time.

Finally, to get the exact answer asked for in the question, you need to add 1 to the position because Python indexes arrays starting from 0, not 1.

```
def subs(string,subString):
    lista = []
    i = 0
    while i < (len(string)-len(subString)):
        if string[i:i+len(subString)] == subString:
           lista.append(i + 1)
        i += 1
    return lista
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? How do you run it, and what do you see?

Comment: run: `subs('GATATATGCATATACTT','ATAT')`
output: `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using regular expressions, something like the following:

```
[m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer("(?=ATAT)", "GATATATGCATATACTT")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional style pwned all :D

```
def mysub2(string, sub):    
    return [x+1 for x in range(len(string)) if string[x:x+len(sub)] == sub]




>>> def mysub(string, sub):          
    return [x+1 for x in range(len(string)) if string[x:x+len(sub)] == sub]

>>> st = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
>>> sub2 = "ATAT"
>>> mysub(st, sub2)
[2, 4, 10]
>>>
```